# Add item to totals in pdf invoice

Tags: invoice, discount, pdf, totals, grand-total

We have a pdf invoices with totals displaying both prices with included and excluded tax, but without a subtotal. 
What we need now only on pdf invoices is to display a total when the discount (coupon code) is active. I see that this works, but not on the totals itself:

```
$subtotal = $item->getRowTotal() + $item->getTaxAmount() + $item->getHiddenTaxAmount()
        - $item->getDiscountAmount();
```

What would be the proper way of showing this total line on PDF invoices?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I am wrong but I thought the orders `Grand Total` would include the discount also so that something like the following would give you how much the user has paid:

```
$order->getGrandTotal()
```

If this does not work you can combine the subtotal, shipping amount and then remove the discount:

```
$order->getSubtotal() + $order->getShippingAmount() + $order->getDiscountAmount()
```

Note that on orders the discount are normally stored as a [negative amount](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/19061/158)