# Magento Database: Negative values in sales_flat_order.discount_amount?

Tags: database, sales-order, discount

Looking into my Magento database inside the `sales_flat_order` table, I find - since the day I updated from the 1.4 to the 1.5 version - the values of `discount_amount` being negative (e.g. -5 EUR for a 5 EUR coupon code).

Before that date (in the database), all the `discount_amount` values are positive (e.g. 5 EUR for a 5 EUR coupon code).

Now I'm puzzled. Does Magento by standard store positive or negative values into the `sales_flat_order` table?

I assume that there should be a positive number in that field and the negative number has been introduced in error. However gaining some clarification through feedback by others would be great.

Additional notes:

- The database design itself allows to store both negative and positive values in that column.
- In the admin, orders with both a positive or negative `discount_amount` (and `base_discount_amount`) do behave exactly the same with the only difference having the number displayed as negative or positive. But negative numbers magically get multiplied by -1 in the calculation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The discount amounts on the complete order are stored with negative amounts, but are stored positively against each item that they effect.

- Negative `sales_flat_order`
- Positive `sales_flat_order_item`

The negative values is stored against the table `sales_flat_quote_address` and then copied across to the table `sales_flat_order`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info, this really gives me a better understanding!